# SQL Query for designing a table which has a column that accepts only 1 alphabet and 2 digits total 3 characters

Tags: sqlite, check-constraints

if we create a table x and it has a column y, then column y should only accept values containing alphanumeric value for example "A39".

```
CREATE TABLE X
(
  Y Text not null check (length(Y)('[A-Z]','[0-9]','[0-9]' ,3)) 
);
```

I am not able to run this code, I am not sure if this is the way, which constraint should i use here?

Comment: You are looking for the REGEXP operator: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GLOB` for this check:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE x (y TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (y GLOB '[A-Z][0-9][0-9]'));
sqlite> INSERT INTO x VALUES ('A01');
sqlite> INSERT INTO x VALUES ('A01Z');
Error: CHECK constraint failed: x
```

> The `GLOB` operator is similar to `LIKE` but uses the Unix file globbing syntax for its wildcards. Also, `GLOB` is case sensitive, unlike `LIKE`.

So if you want lower-case letters too, use `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[A-Z]`.